# Using SELECT UNION and returning output of two columns from one table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

I am creating a query that counts the amount of male and female actors in my table. My current statement is as such:

```
Select COUNT(ActorGender) “Male Actors” 
from (tblActor ta WHERE ta.ActorGender in(‘m’)
UNION
Select COUNT(ActorGender) “Female Actors” 
from tblActor ta 
WHERE ta.ActorGender in(‘f’);
```

The output ends up being:

```
Male Actors
-----------
          7
         21
```

I want the output to look like:

```
Male Actors   Female Actors
-----------   -------------
          7              21
```

I am looking for an alternative to go about this **without using the CASE WHEN or THEN clauses**.

Thanks in advance for the help as usual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

another way without using case:

```
select sum(males) as "Male Actors", sum(females) as "Female Actors" 
from 
(select count(actorGender) as Males, 0 as Females
from tblActor 
where actorGender = 'm'
union all
select 0 as males, count(actorGender) as Females
from tblActor
where actorGender = 'f')
```

should result in

```
Male Actors    Female Actors
-----------    -------------
7              21
```

Comment: nice work-around, I had a similar problem where I needed to combine two unrelated queries into two adjacent columns... really nice work-around :P... I was already going mad, and it's so simple!

Answer (score 9):

Another way (without `CASE` expression):

```
SELECT 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tblActor 
    WHERE ActorGender = 'm' 
  ) AS MaleActors
, ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tblActor 
    WHERE ActorGender = 'f' 
  ) AS FemaleActors
FROM 
    dual ;
```

and more solution with `CROSS` join:

```
SELECT m.MaleActors, f.FemaleActors
FROM 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaleActors
    FROM tblActor 
    WHERE ActorGender = 'm' 
  ) m
  CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS FemaleActors
    FROM tblActor 
    WHERE ActorGender = 'f' 
  ) f  ;
```

Comment: The 1st query on MySQL 5.7.23 works also without the ending `"FROM DUAL"`

Comment: @MarcoDemaio correct. The question is tagged Oracle though (not mysql)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I know, I gave you +1, I was only adding info of general interest :-)

Answer (score 8):

This would do:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN ActorGender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) MaleActors,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActorGender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) FemaleActors
FROM tblActor 
WHERE ActorGender IN ('m','f')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, works like a charm. I only wish there was an alternative to go about this without using the CASE WHEN clauses...

Comment: @learnenburn There is, you can use `PIVOT`, but for two elements, case seems easier to me

Comment: @Lamak `PIVOT` will only work if it is Oracle 11g+ for anything else you have to use your version. :)

Comment: @bluefeet You are right, my comment was more of an invitation for you to write said answer, actually ;-)

Comment: @Lamak you asked, I answered. :)

Comment: Can you use only joins on this even though it's one table to get this answer? I haven't been taught CASE or PIVOT...

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Oracle 11g+, then you can use `PIVOT`:

```
select *
from
(
  select actorgender
  from tblActor
) src
pivot
(
  count(actorgender)
  for actorgender in ('m' MaleActors, 'f' FemaleActors)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd39e/3)

The result would be:

```
| MALEACTORS | FEMALEACTORS |
-----------------------------
|          4 |            5 |
```

Or you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to get the same result:

```
select m.MaleActors, f.FemaleActors
from 
(
  select count(ActorGender) MaleActors, 'm' Gender
  from tblActor
  where ActorGender = 'm'
) m
cross join
(
  select count(ActorGender) FemaleActors, 'f' Gender
  from tblActor
  where ActorGender = 'f'
) f
```