# MySQL Union 2 selects 1 table and output 2 columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

I currently have 1 table and 2 nested selects and I want to union the two nested selects together and I would like the result set to display two different columns one for each result set (one column for each nested select). IE three columns total t_stamp, R02AO11, R03AO11. I've been banging my head on this for a few days now, anyone who can help I would greatly appreciate it. I found this example  [Using SELECT UNION and returning output of two columns from one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592499/using-select-union-and-returning-output-of-two-columns-from-one-table) and it isn't making sense to me -- maybe a bit over my head. Hopefully it isn't too much of a re-post. Thanks again. =)

```
Select t_stamp,
MIN(R02AO11) 
FROM
( 
SELECT 
    t_stamp,
    R02AO11
FROM 
    tag_history 
WHERE 
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) BETWEEN '2012-11-01                                                                                          00:00:00' AND '2012-11-30 23:59:59' 
    AND (R02AO11 IS NOT NULL AND R02AO11 > 0) 
) AS min_tag_history
GROUP BY LEFT(t_stamp, 10)
UNION ## UNION ALL 
Select t_stamp, 
MIN(R03AO11) 
FROM
( 
SELECT 
    t_stamp,
    R03AO11
FROM 
    tag_history 
WHERE 
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) BETWEEN '2012-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-30 23:59:59' 
    AND (R03AO11 IS NOT NULL AND R03AO11 > 0) 
) AS min_tag_history
GROUP BY LEFT(t_stamp, 10)
ORDER BY t_stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you overthinking this or am I missing something?

```
SELECT 
    t_stamp,
    MIN(CASE WHEN R02AO11 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE R02AO11 END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN R03A011 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE R03A011 END)
FROM 
    tag_history 
WHERE 
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)/60)*60) BETWEEN '2012-11-01                                                                                          00:00:00' AND '2012-11-30 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY LEFT(t_stamp, 10)
```

Comment: As you can see in my original query I am first trying to filter out the zeros and the nulls before calling min on the column within the date range. The column contains a bunch of zeros and sometimes nulls and I don't want to call min on it because I always get the zero back. I want the non zero and non null min. 

I do also want to UNION them because specifying multiple columns as non zero and non null in the where clause using AND's or OR's doesn't give me the right result set.

Comment: OK - first forget the nulls min ignores them. I will edit my response to give a SQL Server solution - it may need translation